# torch.load(ml_model) in new class I receive an AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'ResNet1D' on <module '__main__'>

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, google-colaboratory

I have successfully trained a Convolutional neural network model using Google Colab in a file named model_prep.py. The model receives 92% accuracy. Now that i'm happy with the model I have used pyTorch to save my model.

```
torch.save(model, '/content/drive/MyDrive/myModel.pt')
```

My understanding of this is that once the model has been fully trained, I could use pyTorch to save the trained model to then be loaded into future projects for predictions on new data. Therefore I created a separate test.py file where i loaded the trained model like so,

```
model = torch.load('/content/drive/MyDrive/myModel.pt')
model.eval()
```

But within the new test.py file, I receive an error message

```
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'ResNet1D' on <module '__main__'>
```

Although this error does not occur when loading the model in the same notebook as the trained model was created (model_prep.py). This error only occurs when loading the model into a separate notebook with no model architecture. How do I go about this problem? I would like to load the trained model into a new separate file to perform on new data. Can someone suggest a solution?

In the future, I would like to create a GUI using tkinter and deploy the trained model to check predictions using new data within the tkinter file. Is this possible?

Comment: Basically the model saving relies on the global variables at the time of saving like `ResNet1D`. So loading also requires the same global variables to have the same values. Try to define `ResNet1D` the same way you did when training the model. Also please remove the `tkinter` tag from the question as the problem isn't caused directly by `tkinter`.

Answer (score 2):

As stated by Pytorch Blog ([here](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/saving_loading_models.html)) Saving a model in this way will save the entire module using Python’s pickle module. The disadvantage of this approach is that the serialized data is bound to the specific classes and the exact directory structure used when the model is saved. The reason for this is that pickle does not save the model class itself. Rather, it saves a path to the file containing the class, which is used during load time. Because of this, your code can break in various ways when used in other projects or after refactors.

I fixed this with the TorchScript approach. We save model with

```
model_scripted = torch.jit.script(model)# Export to TorchScript

model_scripted.save('model_scripted.pt') # Save
```

and to load it

```
model = torch.jit.load('model_scripted.pt')
model.eval()
```

More details [here](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/saving_loading_models.html#export-load-model-in-torchscript-format)

Answer (score 0):

1. Even I was facing the same error. What this trying to say is create an instance of your model by calling the class and then do `torch.load()`.
2. If go to one of blogs on [Saving and Loading Models](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/saving_loading_models.html) by PyTorch and there in **load** section, you can clearly see this line `# Model class must be defined somewhere`.
3. Hence I would recommend, in your `test.py` file try to define the model class as you have done in `train.py` (guessing this is your filename where you have created your model) and then load as shown below.

```py
model = ModelClass()
model = torch.load(PATH, , map_location=torch.device('cpu')) #<--- if current device is 'CPU'
model.eval() #<---- To prevent it from going to retraining mode.
```